# IFrame button click event

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to attach an eventlistener to the "click" event of a button on a page in an IFrame. The page in the iframe belongs to the same domain as the parent window.

```
window.frames["iframe_Id"].document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click",functionToRun,false);
```

The above sample is not working for me. It could just be a a syntax error in my actual code but I wanted to see if this is the general idea.

**Note:** I found plenty of examples on adding the click event to the entire Iframe but I'm not sure it works the same for buttons within the Iframe.

Comment: Doesn't work in what browser(s)? Frame documents can be tricky.

Comment: Chrome. But I can get the "innerHTML" component of elements within the Iframe when I'm testing, so my gut says it's not the browser and more of something I'm doing.

Comment: Interesting. That suggests the issue is not with finding the button (as current answers attempt to rectify), but assigning/executing the handler...

Comment: Never hurts to double-check the spelling of `functionToRun` at declaration and reference, at that point. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#iframe_Id").contents("#button_id").click(functionToRun);
```

Or without jQuery:

```
document.getElementById("iframe_Id").contentWindow.document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click", functionToRun, false);
```

This will only work if the iframe meets the [same origin policy.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 1):

window.frames is an array-like object, so its elements can be accessed by indexes only.

You should loop through them, and check their id, e.g.:

```
var frame; for(i = 0; i < frames.length; i++) {
    frame = frames[i];
    if (frame.id === 'iframe_id') {
         frame.document
              .getElementById("button_id")
              .addEventListener("click",functionToRun,false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.frames["iframe_Id"].contentWindow.document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click",functionToRun,false);

                              ^
```

The **[contentWindow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe)** property.

> From the DOM iframe element, scripts can get access to the window
>   object of the included HTML page via the contentWindow property.

Comment: That reference page is woefully sparse... haha.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the event in the ["capturing" vs. "bubbling"](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) phase?

```
document.getElementById("iframe_Id")
 .document.addEventListener("click", functionToRun, true);
```

Note the `true` instead of `false` as the final parameter.

Comment: Yea. Same result. I can get the data inside the <button> element but I guess the problem must be around the event registration. I'm still looking over it.