# Detecting a click within an iFrame which triggers the execution of a function (using only Javascript)

Tags: javascript, iframe

This topic has been covered a few times but there is no clear solution using Javascript. All responses were quite nebulous. Please help me out as there hasn't been a straightforward answer anywhere that I could find on any site.

I am trying to execute a function when *any* click occurs within an iframe window. Specifically, a click on a hyperlink on page displayed within the iframe. However just being able to have *any* click within an iframe trigger a function is enough for me.

I have a function Show() that I would like to run when an iframe is clicked. So basically a link is automatically hidden and when the first link is clicked it is shown. When the "click to hide" link that shows up is clicked, the "click to hide" link is hidden. I want the "click to hide" link to show up when someone clicks within the iframe. I need it to run the function every time a click occurs within the iframe. Thanks.

Code:

```html
<html>
  <head>


  <title>StackOverflow Example</title>


  <style>
  .visible {visibility: visible}
  .hidden {visibility: hidden}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var visible_link = true;
  function Hide() {
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
  }
  function Show() {

   
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";
    
    
  }
 
  </script>


  </head>



  <body>

<center>


<iframe src="http://www.google.com" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello"></iframe>

<a href="http://www.google.com" target = "hello" onclick = "Show();">click to show below link</a>

    <div id="my_div" class="hidden">
      <a href="http://www.google.com" target="hello" onclick = "Hide();" >click me to hide</a>
    </div>


    
</center>  

</body>

</html>
```

If there is some kind of domain issue please explain and please, if you have time and are able, explain what the issue is and how to fix such a problem. Edits to this code are welcome for the sake of coming up with a solution that achieves the goal that I outlined.

You guys are great.

**UPDATE**

I have implemented apaul34208's response which technically works, but I am having three problems.

1) How can this take up the full width of the window (I tried adding 100% to the width value under #cover)

2) When the div covers all of the iframe, the webpage within the iframe is not clickable

3) The div is not transparent.

If someone can edit the below code and have  the div take up all of the width while being transparent with the iframe's webpage being entirely clickable - I would be very appreciative and happy.

```html
<html>
  <head>


  <title>Show / Hide Link</title>


  <style>
  .visible {visibility: visible}
  .hidden {visibility: hidden}
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* added for example */
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var visible_link = true;
  function Hide() {
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
  }
  function Show() {

   
      document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
      document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";
    
    
  }
 
  </script>


  </head>



  <body>

<center>

<div id="cover" onclick="Show();"></div>
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello"></iframe>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target = "hello" onclick = "Show();">links</a>

    <div id="my_div" class="hidden">
      <a href="http://stackoverflow.com" target="hello" onclick = "Hide();" ><-</a>
    </div>


    
</center>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If the iframe is in a different domain, the Same Origin Policy applies. You can not touch the iframe since it is from a different domain.

Comment: Do you own the page in the iframe?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: In response to apaul34208 (the first question): The page in the iframe is always my own written page in my own web hosting space.

Comment: @Bergo In that case http://stackoverflow.com/q/13214522/1947286

Comment: Did you miss the "**Please don't ever do this.**"

Comment: I got your message. If you need to contact users on the site you can just use `@username` in the comment section, most people prefer not to be contacted through their personal websites/email addresses about questions here.

Comment: Some one already asked a similar question, you should be able to find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13214522/1947286

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against doing this for any reason, this is usually referred to as ["Clickjacking"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), and it is an extremely bad practice.

**So... Please don't ever do this.**

But for educational purposes... You can cover an iframe with another positioned element and capture the click on that element:

```js
var visible_link = true;

function Hide() {
  document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
  document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
}

function Show() {
  document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
  document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";
}
```

```css
.visible {
  visibility: visible
}
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden
}
#cover {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* added for example */
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cover" onclick="Show();"></div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://stackoverflow.com"></iframe>

<div id="my_div" class="hidden">
  <a href="http://www.google.com" target="hello" onclick="Hide();">click me to hide</a>
</div>
```

**Once again. Don't ever do this.**

Comment: I tried this solution and had two problems:

1) The div is not transparent.

2) With the div there the user cannot click anything on the webpage that is within the iframe.

I may be doing something wrong. Could someone please paste code in its entirety that you feel works?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's not perfect but I figured out that I don't really need to it to detect every iframe click and this is good enough. I originally wanted to make a back button appear if a link within the page that is within the iframe was clicked (which would return the user to the main page within the iframe where they started). Obviously they may click randomly and not hit a hyperlink and the back link would pop up for no reason (while they are still on the main page). That's fine I guess but if someone knows of a better solution let me know. Most people would just hit a link to begin with as the page only has hyperlink interaction I presume.

I hope my working code below helps people who are exploring this topic in the future.

Code:

```html
<html>
<head>


<title>StackOverflow Example</title>


<style>
.visible {visibility: visible}
.hidden {visibility: hidden}

}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var visible_link = true;

var inIframe = false;
function Hide() {
document.getElementById("my_div").className = "hidden";
document.getElementById("my_button").value = "SHOW";
}
function Show() {


document.getElementById("my_div").className = "visible";
document.getElementById("my_button").value = "HIDE";


}


function checkClick() {
if (document.activeElement 
&& document.activeElement === document.getElementById("hello")) {
if (inIframe == false) {
Show();
inIframe = true;
}
} else
inIframe = false;
}
setInterval(checkClick, 200);

</script>


</head>



<body>

<center>

<div id="cover" onclick="Show();"></div>
<iframe src="http://w3schools.com" height=549 width=100% frameborder=0 name = "hello" id = "hello" style =""></iframe>

<a href="http://w3schools.com" target = "hello" onclick = "Show();">click to show link</a>

<div id="my_div" class="hidden">
<a href="http://w3schools.com" target="hello" onclick = "Hide();" >click to hide</a>
</div>



</center> 

</body>

</html>
```